# Get a number from a string using charCodeAt

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fromcharcode

Need to get a number using only one loop for and `charCodeAt()`
We can't use native methods and concatenations, parseInt, parseFloat, Number, +str, 1 * str, 1 / str, 0 + str, etcc

```js
const text = "In this market, I lost 0,0000695 USDT, today is not my day";

function getAmount(str) {
  const zero = "0".charCodeAt(0);
  const nine = "9".charCodeAt(0);
  const coma = ",".charCodeAt(0);
  let num = 0,
    factor = 1;

  for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const char = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (char >= zero && char <= nine) {
      num += (char - 48) * factor;
      factor *= 10;
    }
  }
  return num;
};

console.log(getAmount(text));
```

Need result: `0,0000695`
My current result is `695`

Tell me how to correct the formula for writing zeros

Comment: Sounds a lot like a homework question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: That said, have you tried stepping through your code? Browsers can debug javascript. Additionally, you do have a 'comma' constant, but you aren't checking it.
Also, why are you reading from right to left? Why not start from the left, multiplying the number you already have by 10 for every digit?

Comment: can not use parseFloat()

Comment: Your code defines `coma` but doesn't even attempt to use it. Have you tried thinking through the algorithm on paper, on in pseducode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit a comma, you need to convert the current value to a fraction:

```js
const getAmount = (str) => {
    const zero = "0".charCodeAt(0);
    const nine = "9".charCodeAt(0);
    const comma = ",".charCodeAt(0);
    let num = NaN, // Init to NaN as a sentinal value. Could also use null.
        factor = 1;      
    let haveComma = false;

    for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        // Break when: it's not a number and not a comma, but we have parsed number
        const isParsable = (char == comma && !haveComma) || !isNaN(str.charAt(i));
        if (!isParsable && !isNaN(num)) break;
        else if (char >= zero && char <= nine) {
            if (isNaN(num)) num = 0; // Reset from NaN to Zero, first time only
            num += (char - 48) * factor;
            factor *= 10;
        }
        // On comma, convert num to a fraction and reset factor
        // Ex: num = 123 -> num = .123
        else if (char == comma && !isNaN(num)) {
            num /= factor;
            factor = 1;
            haveComma = true;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

const text = "In this market I lost $10,0000695 USDT, today is not my day";
console.log(getAmount(text));
```

---

I just noticed that my answer is similar to a [previously deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78148486/669576) answer. The issue with that answer is that they did not handle multiple commas in the string.

Comment: How can we avoid using space? Can we break out of a loop using only true\false flags?